# create method number generator in c# by parameter

Tags: c#

I tried to Create a method to get value from the user then make a number generator of those values as a parameter but I Did not knew how !

```
 //create a method that genereted the number of taple game
  public void zahra() 
  {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter value to random them betwen ");
        Console.Write("from ");
        ran    = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\n to ");
        to = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        to++;
  }
```

Comment: use [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
// declare random instance outside of the method 
// because we don't want duplicate numbers
static Random rnd = new Random();

public static int GenerateRandomNumber()
{
    // declare variables to store range of number
    int from, to;

    // use while(true) and force user to enter valid numbers
    while(true)
    {
        // we use TryParse in order to avoid FormatException and validate the input
        bool a = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out from);
        bool b = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out to);

        // check values and ensure that 'to' is greater than 'from'
        // otherwise we will get a ArgumentOutOfRangeException on rnd.Next

        if(a && b && from < to) break; // if condition satisfies break the loop

        // otherwise display a message and ask for input again
        else Console.WriteLine("You have entered invalid numbers, please try again.");
    }

    // generate a random number and return it
    return rnd.Next(from, to + 1);

}
```

Comment: man i don't understand this can you comment what have you done out there , and how can i call this in the main

Comment: if you want to call it from `Main`, make it static.then just call it like this: `"int random = GenerateRandomNumber();"`

Comment: `TryParse` takes a string input and try to parse it to an `integer`.If it's succeeded it returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`.unlike `Parse` method, it doesn't throw exception  when the input string is in invalid format

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the end of your script:

```
 Random r=new Random();
 Console.WriteLine(r.Next(ran, to));
```

of course you should declare `ran` and `to` as int.

edit:This is my whole project code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RND
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        zahra();
    }
    public static void zahra()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter value to random them betwen ");
        Console.Write("from ");
        int ran = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\n to ");
        int to = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        to++;

        Random r=new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(r.Next(ran, to));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: in my computer it works. what is the error? i am adding my code